# How to await candidates in WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, async-await, webrtc

Is there any easy way to `await` the full completed with candidates ? We can `await` the offer & description, but I dont see a way to await the candidates (full sdp to be sent to the signalling server).

E.g.:

```js
const pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
const sendChannel = pc.createDataChannel("sendChannel");
const offer = await pc.createOffer();
await pc.setLocalDescription(offer);

// need something like this;
await pc.onIceCandidateComplete();; 

// send the offer to signaling server once we have all the data.
send(offer);
```

I see there `oniceconnectionstatechange()`, and `onicecandidate()` that can be used, but none support `await async`, or I can't find a good example.

Has anyone come up with a good solution for this or is there some reason to not have this functionality? What's the best way?

Comment: (Just a nitpick) Actually `async`/`await` is ES2017, not ES6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no directly awaitable event. You can use a construct like the waitUntilEvent function found [here](https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/blob/master/webrtc/RTCPeerConnection-helper.js#L191):

```
await (new Promise(r => {
  pc.addEventListener(
    'icegatheringstatechange',
    () => pc.gatheringState === 'complete' && r()
 )
}));
```

Note however that this state change can take a lot of time (30s+) in certain cases. [This bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=7844) has some notes. Typically you'll want to wait for other conditions like the first relay candidate or add a timeout.